# In which case does GitHub mark a file "changed" whose body was actually not changed?

Tags: git, github

My developer just made some commits, I tried to compare his last commit with one previous commit, and here is the result:

[image]

I just don't understand why GitHub marks many files **changed**, whereas actually their body did not change. `latest-website/.gitignore`, `latest-website/README.md`, etc. were all like that.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did the text editor your developer use alter the line breaks or convert between tabs and spaces?

Comment: I don't think so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard telling without doing a `git diff` to see what it may be.

The two most common I have come across are the following.

1. Due to the change in line endings. They may have changed from `CRLF` (Windows) to `LF` (Unix) or vice versa.

To better handle this option you can do `git config core.autocrlf input`

2. Doing a `git diff` shows old mode and new mode have different file permissions for each file. For example `777` given to all of the local files whereas the repo has `755`.

As Mike said in a comment, sometimes I'll see a change from tabs to spaces or 2 space vs 4 space. To combat that issue, we have a `.editorconfig` file.

Comment: `git diff ea9ee9b7254f9293bd57dc15c651474c383cb584..f0f05f42a5822a1e28f68ca83a72b51ed0505a21 -- latest-website/README.md` does show many `^M` in the later version. I guess it is because the files were transformed in his Windows.